# Oracle merge with stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

Data is not getting inserted, this is what I have, using Oracle 21c Express.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE UPSERTREADINGS 
(
   STATION_ID NVARCHAR2
 , READING_DATE TIMESTAMP 
 , READING_TYPE NVARCHAR2 
 , RESULT_VALUE NUMBER 
 , RESULT_TEXT NVARCHAR2 
 , RESULT_UNIT NVARCHAR2 
 , READING_STATUS NVARCHAR2 
 , ACTIVITY_TYPE NVARCHAR2 
 , COMMENTS NVARCHAR2 
 , SOURCE_FILE_ID NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO READINGS r
        USING (SELECT STATION_ID, READING_DATE, READING_TYPE, RESULT_VALUE, RESULT_TEXT, RESULT_UNIT, 
        READING_STATUS, ACTIVITY_TYPE, COMMENTS, SOURCE_FILE_ID FROM READINGS) e 
        ON ( r.STATION_ID = e.STATION_ID AND r.READING_DATE = e.READING_DATE 
            AND r.READING_TYPE = e.READING_TYPE )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET 
            r.RESULT_VALUE = UPSERTREADINGS.RESULT_VALUE,
            r.RESULT_TEXT = UPSERTREADINGS.RESULT_TEXT,
            r.RESULT_UNIT = UPSERTREADINGS.RESULT_UNIT,
            r.READING_STATUS = UPSERTREADINGS.READING_STATUS,
            r.ACTIVITY_TYPE = UPSERTREADINGS.ACTIVITY_TYPE,
            r.COMMENTS = UPSERTREADINGS.COMMENTS,
            r.SOURCE_FILE_ID = UPSERTREADINGS.SOURCE_FILE_ID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT (STATION_ID, READING_DATE, READING_TYPE, RESULT_VALUE, RESULT_TEXT, RESULT_UNIT, READING_STATUS, ACTIVITY_TYPE, COMMENTS, SOURCE_FILE_ID) 
        VALUES (UPSERTREADINGS.STATION_ID, UPSERTREADINGS.READING_DATE, UPSERTREADINGS.READING_TYPE, UPSERTREADINGS.RESULT_VALUE, UPSERTREADINGS.RESULT_TEXT, 
            UPSERTREADINGS.RESULT_UNIT, UPSERTREADINGS.READING_STATUS, UPSERTREADINGS.ACTIVITY_TYPE, UPSERTREADINGS.COMMENTS, UPSERTREADINGS.SOURCE_FILE_ID);
    COMMIT;
END UPSERTREADINGS;
```

I have tried using e.<COLUMN_NAME> instead of UPSERTREADINGS.<COLUMN_NAME> but it is not clear where to use e or <PROCEDURE_NAME>.

Thanks

Comment: You are merging data from a table into the same table and you aren't amending the join columns. Why would you expect data to be inserted? All the rows are already in the table, so you're basically just doing an update. I suspect what you want is to replace the source query with `select <list of params, aliased appropriately> from dual` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it, thanks to some help from @Boneist

```
create or replace PROCEDURE UPSERTREADINGS 
(
  STATION_ID NVARCHAR2
, READING_DATE TIMESTAMP 
, READING_TYPE NVARCHAR2 
, RESULT_VALUE NUMBER 
, RESULT_TEXT NVARCHAR2 
, RESULT_UNIT NVARCHAR2 
, READING_STATUS NVARCHAR2 
, ACTIVITY_TYPE NVARCHAR2 
, COMMENTS NVARCHAR2 
, SOURCE_FILE_ID NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
    MERGE INTO READINGS r
        USING (SELECT UPSERTREADINGS.STATION_ID As StationID, UPSERTREADINGS.READING_DATE As ReadingDate, UPSERTREADINGS.READING_TYPE As ReadingType, UPSERTREADINGS.RESULT_VALUE As ResultValue, 
        UPSERTREADINGS.RESULT_TEXT As ResultText,     UPSERTREADINGS.RESULT_UNIT As ResultUnit, UPSERTREADINGS.READING_STATUS As     ReadingStatus, UPSERTREADINGS.ACTIVITY_TYPE As ActivityType, 
            UPSERTREADINGS.COMMENTS As Comments, UPSERTREADINGS.SOURCE_FILE_ID As SourceFileID FROM dual) e 
        ON ( r.STATION_ID = UPSERTREADINGS.STATION_ID AND r.READING_DATE = UPSERTREADINGS.READING_DATE AND r.READING_TYPE = UPSERTREADINGS.READING_TYPE )
    WHEN MATCHED THEN 
        UPDATE SET 
            r.RESULT_VALUE = e.ResultValue,
            r.RESULT_TEXT = e.ResultText,
            r.RESULT_UNIT = e.ResultUnit,
            r.READING_STATUS = e.ReadingStatus,
            r.ACTIVITY_TYPE = e.ActivityType,
            r.COMMENTS = e.Comments,
            r.SOURCE_FILE_ID = e.SourceFileID
    WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
        INSERT (STATION_ID, READING_DATE, READING_TYPE, RESULT_VALUE, RESULT_TEXT, RESULT_UNIT, READING_STATUS, ACTIVITY_TYPE, COMMENTS, SOURCE_FILE_ID) 
        VALUES (e.StationID, e.ReadingDate, e.ReadingType, e.ResultValue, e.ResultText, e.ResultUnit, e.ReadingStatus, e.ActivityType, e.Comments, e.SourceFileID);
    COMMIT;
END UPSERTREADINGS;
```